# Требуется напечатать русский текст с помощью PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, кириллица

Требуется печатать текст на русском для автоматизации некоторых процессов. Нашёл такую вещь, как PyAutoGUI, но с русским текстом она не работает, печатает оттуда только пробелы и символы. Есть ли возможность поправить это или существует какая-нибудь альтернатива?

```
import pyautogui as pag
import os, time
os.startfile('notepad.exe')
time.sleep(2)
pag.typewrite('Привет, как вы можете видеть+выводятся_только\пробелы и символы', interval=0.1)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/789985 может поможет, поищи в гугле или на форумах

Comment: готово, предоставил

Comment: Уже же говорили что кирилица не поддерживается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вот это решение:

```
import pyautogui as pag
import os, time
import pyperclip, keyboard, time
os.startfile('notepad.exe')
def paste(text: str):    
    buffer = pyperclip.paste()
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + v')
    pyperclip.copy(buffer)



def type(text: str, interval=0.0):    
   if interval == 0.0:
       paste(text)
       return

   buffer = pyperclip.paste()
   for char in text:
       pyperclip.copy(char)
       keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + v')
       time.sleep(0.1)
   pyperclip.copy(buffer)

type('  Привет, как вы можете видеть+выводятся_только\пробелы и символы', 0.1)
```

Comment: На pywinauto это делается в три строчки (там поддержка юникода). Что вы в этом pyautogui нашли? Кроме популярности автора книг.